Impossible to use DATEDIFF in java JPA criteria queries?
For the life of me, I cannot figure this out.
I want to select entities from my H2 database, and get the difference between an entities timestamp column and a passed parameter.
trying
var dateDiff = cb.function("DATEDIFF", BigInteger.class, cb.literal("NANOSECOND"), cb.parameter(OffsetDateTime.class, "startTime"), eventViewEnt.get(EventViewEntity_.timestamp));
causes the error (paraphrasing) 'parameter 1 (the nanosecond literal) is supposed to be of type Temporal Unit, but got Object.
For the life of me i cannot figure out how to pass NANOSECOND into this function. Other possible solutions require i i pass a temporal unit also...

Parameter 1 =  BigInteger.class ?

@K.Nicholas for cb.function, the second parameter is BigInt ya, but that parameter is actually the Result Type of the sql function (the previous parameter), everything after that are parameters that get passed to the sql function specified in the first parameter of cb.function. The error is about the first parameter passed to the sql func, which means the third parameter of the cb.function call. its cb.func(SqlFuncName, SqlFuncReturnType, sqlParmeter1, sqlparametrr2…)
